# Promises in JS: using Axios to write to mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, promise, axios

I am struggling to get my head round Promises.  I think i understand the concept but I am unable to get them to work on the backend.

I have read several stackoverflow posts. I still see a few which are only months old so I guess i am not the only one :)

Specifically, I need help on how I can pass the result of a resolved promise within my code. In the code below, I fetch a JSON file from the starwars api and want to write it onto a mongodb atlas collection.

I use axios.get, which returns a promise. I then resolve it using .then and then use insertOne on mongoDB collections.

On the frontend for e.g in React, it works as expected, where you use setState to change the state by using the setState within the .then function. 
I don't understand why it doesn't work in the backend.

Could you please tell me what I need to change so I can get it to write to mongoDB atlas?

```
var axios = require("axios");
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
var db;

const getData = () => {
  return axios
    .get("https://swapi.co/api/people/1")
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.data) throw Error("No data found.");
         console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data))  **//This returns the data as expected.**
         return JSON.stringify(response.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      throw error;
    });
};

console.log(getData()); **// This returns {Promise <pending>}**


const client = new MongoClient(process.env.MONGODB_URL, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});

// Connect to database and insert default users into users collection
client.connect(err => {

  console.log("Connected successfully to database");

  let d = {
    name: "Luke Skywalker",
    height: "172",
    mass: "77",
    hair_color: "blond",
    skin_color: "fair",
    eye_color: "blue"
  };



  db = client.db(process.env.DB_NAME);
  db.collection("macroData").insertOne(d);  //this works
  db.collection("macroData").insertOne(getData); // this doesn't work as it still appears to  be a promise
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`getData()` returns a Promise, as you are well aware, so you have to wait on that promise to resolve. A straightforward approach would be to perform the insert once the data is available:

```js
  client.connect(err => {
    // ...
    getData().then(data => {
      db.collection('macroData').insertOne(data)
    })
  })
```

Or, if you can use async/await:

```js
client.connect(async err => {
  // ...
  const data = await getData()

  db.collection('macroData').insertOne(data)
})
```

Comment: worked !  Added a few  try catch to find errors as that made it easier for me to figure out what was going wrong.  The updated code is here.                                                                                                                    
    `getData(url)
    .then(data => {
      try {
        db.collection("macroData").insertOne(data);
        console.log("Insert worked");
      } catch {
        console.log("Insert failed");
      }
    })
    .catch(err => Error("something broke"))`

Comment: Glad it worked out for you - I didn't include error checking just to be succinct. Obviously you should check for validity before inserting and catching potential issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your mongodb call needs to be within the axios promise, that way the resolved promise can be used to feed your database. That's what held me up for a while...

The code below is for Nick comment, I couldn't post the code in the comment as it was too long.  You should have a database named test or appropriate name here `let datab = client.db('test')`, i think it comes by default when you create a mongodb atlas.
if you change your user and password in the mongourl, you should be good to go.
Hope that helps. This creates a starwars entry under test.starWarsData  .. hope t

```
let axios = require("axios");
let MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
let mongoParams = { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true };

let mongoUrl =
  "mongodb+srv://user:password@cluster0-hnc4i.azure.mongodb.net/test";
//try feeding just the object e, and see if it works, in case your axios error catching is not great.
let e = {
  a: "this is a",
  b: "this is b",
  c: "this is c",
  d: "this is d"
};

let newUrl = "https://swapi.co/api/people/1";

console.log(newUrl);

let client = new MongoClient(mongoUrl, mongoParams);

client.connect(err => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    throw new Error("failed to connect");
  }

  let datab = client.db("test");
  console.log("db connected");

  try {
    axios.get(newUrl).then(res => {
      try {
        datab.collection("starWarsData").insertOne(res.data);
        console.log("insert succeeded");
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("insert failed");
        console.log(err.message);
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    throw Error("axios get did not work");
  }
});
```